# Can I use DirectoryEntry to list sites within IIS Express

Tags: c#, iis-express

I am on Windows XP.  We have Windows 2008 Servers.  Need to run IIS Express until we get workstations or virtual machines with newer version of local O.S. for the real IIS 7.X.

Can I use DirectoryEntry to list my Sites and Virtual Directories when I run c# code under IIS Express?  I have examples for setting up the Virtual Directories under IIS Express so that I think I have covered.  Now I want to list them to ensure they exist.

Anyone know how to do this in C#?  Just a small snippet of what I have been trying causes com exceptions...

```
DirectoryEntry iisServer = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1");
DirectoryEntry folderRoot = iisServer.Children.Find("Root", "/");
var children = folderRoot.Children;
```

Comment: @DJKRAZE: The OP said COM exceptions.

Comment: @leppie I posted and example for him to try I didn't see that he had or was getting COM Exception since I am use to see "COM" in upper case.. lol thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
void ListVirtualDirectories(string serverName, int siteId)
{            
       DirectoryEntry iisServer = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + serverName + "/W3SVC/" + siteId + "/ROOT");

       foreach (DirectoryEntry webDir in iisServer.Children)
       {
           if (webDir.SchemaClassName.Equals("IIsWebVirtualDir"))
               Console.WriteLine("Found virtual directory {0}", webDir.Name);
       }
}
```

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unknown error (0x80005000)  This sample code still returns this error.

Comment: The error is returned when trying to iterate over iisServer.Children.

Comment: That's a permissions error in ActiveDirectory google the error (0x80005000)