# How to correctly link the installed web application name and its virtual directory name?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, registry, installation

Using ServerManager, I can get the list of virtual directories for my installed web applications. I can also verify if a specific web application is installed using registry key search. I am, however, unable to locate the web application physical path that is usually in inetpub\wwwroot.

InstallLocation field in the related registry does not have any value. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DirectoryEntry` to browse the IIS configuration. Here is an example pulled from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13696452/1202807):

```
void ListVirtualDirectories(string serverName, int siteId) {            
   DirectoryEntry iisServer = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + serverName + "/W3SVC/" + siteId + "/ROOT");

   foreach (DirectoryEntry webDir in iisServer.Children) {
       if (webDir.SchemaClassName.Equals("IIsWebVirtualDir"))
               Console.WriteLine("Found virtual directory {0}", webDir.Name);
   }
}
```

The `siteId` is a numerical value corresponding to each site listed in IIS. This method forces you to provide it, but you could find all the sites on the server too if you wanted. Just search Google for that if you need it. But this should get you started.

Comment: The issue here is not listing the available websites in a IIS but rather how to link a particular website's virtual directory with its installer product name. 

For instance you can install a web application on your machine named "ABC DEF" but during installation you can rename the virtual directory of this program to "XYZ". I can find both names but I don't know how to relate them. When you uninstall the program "ABC DEF", Windows knows how to remove the associated files from the related virtual directory "XYZ". So this must be saved somewhere!

Comment: This code lists the virtual directories in a specific website. And if you can see the properties of a virtual directory, then you can read the physical path.